# Memory allocation and deallocation

Tags: string, oop, memory-management, memory-leaks

Here is the entire program, please help me, I've tried everything to find out what exactly is going with the memory. The problem is everything runs perfectly, but there are some extra characters printed with output.

Here is the .h file:

```
 class MyString
 {
    public:
            MyString();
            MyString(const char *message);
            MyString(const MyString &source);
            ~MyString();
            const void Print() const;
            const int Length() const;
            MyString& operator()(const int index, const char b);
            char& operator()(const int i);

            MyString& operator=(const MyString& rhs);
            bool operator==(const MyString& other) const;
            bool operator!=(const MyString& other) const;
            const MyString operator+(const MyString& rhs) const;
            MyString& operator+=(const MyString& rhs);
            friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const MyString& rhs);
            const int Find(const MyString& other);
            MyString Substring(int start, int length);

    private:
            char *String;
            int Size;


 };

 istream& operator>>(istream& input, MyString& rhs);
```

The .cpp file:

```
 MyString::MyString()
 {
    char temp[] = "Hello World";

    int counter(0);
    while(temp[counter] != '\0')
    {
            counter++;
    }
    Size = counter;
    String = new char [Size];
    for(int i=0; i < Size; i++)
            String[i] = temp[i];

 }

 //alternate constructor that allows for setting of the inital value of the string

  MyString::MyString(const char *message)
  {
    int counter(0);
    while(message[counter] != '\0')
    {
            counter++;
    }
    Size = counter;
    String = new char [Size];
    for(int i=0; i < Size; i++)
            String[i] = message[i];
 }

 //copy constructor
 MyString::MyString(const MyString &source)
 {

    int counter(0);
    while(source.String[counter] != '\0')
    {
       counter++;
    }
    Size = counter+1;
    String = new char[Size];
    for(int i = 0; i <= Size; i++)
            String[i] = source.String[i];


 }

 //Deconstructor
 MyString::~MyString()
 {
    delete [] String;
 }

 //Length() method that reports the length of the string
 const int MyString::Length() const
 {
    int counter(0);

    while(String[counter] != '\0')
    {
            counter ++;
    }
    return (counter);
 }

 /*Parenthesis operator should be overloaded to replace the Set and Get functions of  your previous assignment. Note that both instances should issue exit(1) upon violation of the string array bounaries.
 */

    MyString& MyString::operator()(const int index, const char b)
    {
    if(String[index] == '\0')
    {
            exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
            String[index] = b;
    }
 }

 char& MyString::operator()(const int i)
 {
    if(String[i] == '\0')
    {
            exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
            return String[i];
  }
 }
 /*Assignment operator (=) which will copy the source string into the destination string. Note that size of the destination needs to be adjusted to be the same as the source.
 */

 MyString& MyString::operator=(const MyString& rhs)
 {
    if(this != &rhs)
    {
            delete [] String;
            String = new char[rhs.Size];
            Size = rhs.Size;

            for(int i = 0; i < rhs.Size+1 ; i++)
            {
                    String[i] = rhs.String[i];
            }
    }

    return *this;
 }
 /*Logical comparison operator (==) that returns true iff the two strings are identical in size and contents.
 */

  bool MyString::operator==(const MyString& other)const
  {
    if(other.Size == this->Size)  {         
        for(int i = 0; i < this->Size+1; i++)
            {
                    if(&other == this)
                            return true;
            }
    }
    else
            return false;
 }

 //Negated logical comparison operator (!=) that returns boolean negation of 2

 bool MyString::operator!=(const MyString& other) const
 {
    return !(*this == other);
 }

 //Addition operator (+) that concatenates two strings

 const MyString MyString::operator+(const MyString& rhs) const
 {
    char* tmp = new char[Size + rhs.Size +1];


    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
            tmp[i] = String[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < rhs.Size+1; i++)   {           
        tmp[i+Size] = rhs.String[i];
    }

    MyString result;

    delete [] result.String;
    result.String = tmp;
    result.Size = Size+rhs.Size;

    return result;
 }
 /*Addition/Assigment operator (+=) used in the following fashion: String1 += String2 to operate as String1 = String1 + String2
 */

 MyString& MyString::operator+=(const MyString& rhs)
  {
    char* tmp = new char[Size + rhs.Size + 1];

    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)        {
            tmp[i] = String[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < rhs.Size+1; i++)
    {
            tmp[i+Size] = rhs.String[i];
    }

    delete [] String;
    String = tmp;
    Size += rhs.Size;

    return *this;
 }

 istream& operator>>(istream& input, MyString& rhs)
 {
    char* t;
    int size(256);
    t = new char[size];
    input.getline(t,size);

    rhs = MyString(t);
    delete [] t;

    return input;
 }

 ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const MyString& rhs)
 {
    if(rhs.String != '\0')
    {
            output << rhs.String;
    }
    else
    {
            output<<"No String to output\n";
    }

    return output;
 }






 /*MyString::Find that finds a string in a larger string and returns the starting location of the substring. Note that your string location starts from 0 and ends at length -1. If the string is not found, a value of -1 will be returned
 */

 const int MyString::Find(const MyString& other)
 {

    int nfound = -1;

    if(other.Size > Size)
    {
            return nfound;
    }   
      int i = 0, j = 0;      
      for(i = 0; i < Size; i++)    {            
        for(j = 0; j < other.Size; j++)  {            
             if( ((i+j) >= Size) || (String[i+j] != other.String[j]) )

                    {
                            break;
                    }

            }

            if(j == other.Size)
            {

                    return i;

            }

      }


    return nfound;
 }
 /*MyString::Substring(start, length). This method returns a substring of the original string that contains the same characters as the original string starting at location start and is as long as length.
 */

 MyString MyString::Substring(int start, int length)
 {
    char* leo = new char[length+1];
    for(int i = start; i < start + length+1; ++i)
    {
            leo[i-start] = String[i];
    }

    MyString sub;
    delete [] sub.String;        sub.String = leo;        sub.Size = Size;
    return sub;
 }

  //Print() method that prints the string

 const void MyString::Print() const
 {

    for(int i=0; i < Size; i++)
    {
            cout<<String[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
 }
```

The main.cpp file:

```
 int main (int argc, char **argv)
 {

   MyString String1; 

  const MyString ConstString("Target string");    //Test of alternate constructor

   MyString SearchString;  //Test of default constructor that should set "Hello World".

 MyString TargetString (String1); //Test of copy constructor


   cout << "Please enter two strings. ";
  cout << "Each string needs to be shorter than 256 characters or terminated by /\n." << endl;
 cout << "The first string will be searched to see whether it contains exactly the second string. " << endl;

  cin >> SearchString >> TargetString; // Test of cascaded string-extraction operator






   if(SearchString.Find(TargetString) == -1) {

    cout << TargetString << " is not in " << SearchString << endl;
    }

  else {

    cout << TargetString << " is in " << SearchString << endl;

    cout << "Details of the hit: " << endl;

    cout << "Starting position of the hit: " << SearchString.Find(TargetString) << endl;
    cout << "The matching substring is: " << SearchString.Substring(SearchString.Find(TargetString), TargetString.Length()-1)<<"\n";
    }
  return 0;

 }
```

Running the program you get this:

Please enter two strings. Each string needs to be shorter than 256 characters or terminated by /
.
The first string will be searched to see whether it contains exactly the second string.

firstly

real

realt World is not in firstly

Please Help!!

Comment: [Reduce the problem.](http://dev.rootdirectory.de/wiki/MacheteDebugging) This will be much more helpful than any debugging *we* could do here.

Comment: This question is much too long, it would be easier if you give a more succinct question.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a '\0' at the end of your strings in your `MyString::MyString(const char *message)` constructor

Comment: do you mean like the string that is passed in?

Comment: with that constructor the string passed in is defined by: const MyString ConstString("Target string"); so instead, it should be const MyString ConstString("Target string \0");?? I'm sorry I'm sort of new to this

Comment: I I believe that there's already a `\0` at the end of string literals like `"Hello World"`

Comment: oh okay, so I would just have to change my function?

Answer (score 0):

@Sam's answer is correct.  I'm going to add on to it to help you learn what's happening.

C and C++ strings are really character arrays that follow a convention that the string is terminated with `\0`, sometimes called NUL (*not* null), which is a character where all bits are 0.

Your code gets the first part right in that it creates an array of characters.  However, you do not apply the *convention* that the string must be NUL terminated.

You then pass a string that does not follow the NUL termination convention to `cout`, which *does* follow that convention.  In other words, it runs through the string, printing each character to `stdout`, until it *happens* across the character `\0` in memory.  It's actually fairly lucky that it terminates.  If there were not a `\0` in the character array it is outputing, it would just keep on going until reaching a memory address that does not belong to your program and failing with a segmentation fault.

Comment: Thank you so much! So my guess is to add the NUL character by saying something like Size = counter +1 for all constructors. Then, I may have to change the sizes in functions such as my substring function later in the program.